# Header Portion of message in WebSphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

i am very new to  WebSphere MQ someone please tell me how to see header portion of message in WebSphere MQ (7.0.1.3)

Comment: Could you clarify why you trying to achieve please?

Simplest way would be to use the MQExplorer and right click and select Browse Messages... double click on the message and all the information appears.

Comment: i just want to know command to execute in command prompt

Comment: Did @Umapathy's answer tell you what you wanted to know? If yes, please accept it by clicking on the tick. If not, please tell us more about what you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

/opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsbcg on linux can browse the messages for you.  It prints the message header as well as the content.  But you have to be on the same server as MQ qmgr.
If you are on a mq client, /opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsbcgc should do, but you need to use a svrconn channel to connect to the qmgr and browse the messages.